# Running C&C 16 or 32 bit game on a 64 bit system

Tags: command-and-conquer

I have a HP dv5-2135dx laptop, Windows 7 64 bit.What upgrades do I need [if any] to run C&C 16 or 32  bit games on my system.

Comment: Have you already tried XP-compatibility mode?

Comment: None of the C&C games are 16 bit. The _CD installers_ of C&C95 and RA95 sadly are, though, and can't be run at all on 64 bit systems.